# Columns and Rows in Sublime Text 3

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext3

Is it possible in sublime text 3 to split the layout into 2 columns and 2 rows in the same screen? If yes how do you do this on both Mac and Window?

I currently use <kbd>CMD ALT 2</kbd> to split to 2 columns.

So I want the layout to be like this:

```
        |        
        |     
--------|---------
        |
        |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a grid layout available for that. Type <kbd>CMD + ALT + 5</kbd> or Menu > View > Layout > Grid.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted :)